# How to know which DiskId is associated to a given Volume

Tags: powershell, partition, diskmanagement

Using PowerShell I select one `Volume` querying by name and filesystem with this line:

```
$volume = Get-Disk | Get-Partition | Get-Volume | Where { $_.FileSystemType -eq 'NTFS' -and $_.FileSystemLabel -eq 'MainOS' } |  Select -index 0
```

But after that, I want to know in **which Disk** is this `Volume` located.

I thought that the Volume object would have a **DiskId** property, but it doesn't.

Then, how can I know the DiskId of the Volume?

Comment: You might be making your life more difficult by trying to do all of that in a single pipeline.  You almost certainly have the information you need from the Get-Disk,or Get-Partition results, but you won't be easily able access those results after the Get-Volume.

Comment: Should I use nested foreachs then?

Comment: Are you trying to only do this at athe prompt or are you writing a script that you plan to save to a file.

Comment: I'm trying to create a Volume inside the same Disk where the "MainOS" Volume resides. I use this volume to identify the correct disk.

Comment: I'll ask again...Are you trying to do this at the powershell prompt? Or are you doing it in a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, well here is a way to do it. I only have one drive to look at right now but this should point you in the right direction:

```
#Get the Volume labeled MainOS with a File type of NTFS
$volume = Get-Volume -FileSystemLabel | Where-Object{$_.FileSystemType -eq 'NTFS'}
# Use the volume's driveletter to get the partition
$partition = Get-Partition -DriveLetter $volume.DriveLetter
# use the partition's disknumber to get the disk
$disk = Get-Disk -Number $partition.DiskNumber
```